# Can I request only items updated after a certain date?

Tags: square-connect

My app needs to get any items that have been updated since the last time I retrieved the items. Is there a way to pass a date/time parameter to the /items endpoint and only be returned those items which have been updated since that date/time? Otherwise, I need to get back all items and then have to go back for each to get the details in order to determine if their modifiers have changed. This seems very wasteful, plus the batch request that I have to use can take from 10-25 seconds for a batch of 30 items. There are over 400 items defined currently :( Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to filter items by the date of their last update with the Connect API. I've passed this use case along to the API development team.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for passing this on. Hopefully others would benefit from this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the new [Catalog APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-catalog) to more efficiently batch retrieve and batch upsert your item catalog for processing situations like this.